# In GoldenEye, what does 'strikes deferred' refer to?

Tags: penetration-test

Using GoldenEye to launch a DOS attack on a web server, the terminal output reads:

```
12928 GoldenEye strikes deferred. (0 Failed)
```

What does '`strikes deferred`' refer to?

Comment: Unless the program is famous, it would help to link to the program you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the developer's repo](https://github.com/jseidl/GoldenEye/issues/7#issuecomment-269082000):

> "Strikes Deferred" variable saying what number of strikes was blocked
>   or crashed. In brackets says what number of connection timed out was
>   responded (or responded error 500).

You would have to read the code carefully to work this out and it is not obvious or in any of the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

On line [195](https://github.com/jseidl/GoldenEye/blob/master/goldeneye.py#L195) of the source code, you can see that error message:
https://github.com/jseidl/GoldenEye/blob/master/goldeneye.py

I'm assuming that it is being printed because you called the tool with the wrong arguments on the command line.

Comment: line 194 (195 now) is not an error message, it's an output of the stats function

Answer (score -4):

It's not an error message, it just means that that many requests have successfully been sent.

Comment: it's an answer, it's just wrong